# Parse table data into R but it's blank, javascript?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

My first post and a beginner with R so patience requested if I should have found an answer to my question elsewhere.

I'm trying to cobble together a table with data pulled from multiple sites from CME (https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/western-canadian-select-wcs-crude-oil-futures.html is one).

I've tried using rvest but get a blank table.
I think this is because of the Javascript that is being used to populate the table in real time?  I've fumbled my way around this site to look for similar problems and haven't quite figured out how best to pull this data.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
library(rvest)

library(dplyr)

WCS_page <- "https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/canadian-heavy-crude-oil-net-energy-index-futures_quotes_globex.html"
WCS_diff <- read_html(WCS_page)

month <- WCS_diff %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('th') %>%
    xml2::xml_find_all("//scope[contains(@col, 'Month')]") %>%
    rvest::html_text()

price <- WCS_diff %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('tr') %>%
    xml2::xml_find_all("//td[contains(@class, 'quotesFuturesProductTable1_CLK0_last')]") %>%
    rvest::html_text()

WTI_df <- data.frame(month, price)

knitr::kable(
    WTI_df %>% head (10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the page is using JS to load the data.

The easy way to check is to [view source](http://view-source:https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/canadian-heavy-crude-oil-net-energy-index-futures_quotes_globex.html) and then search for some of the text you saw in the table. For example the word "May" never shows up in the raw HTML, so it must have been loaded later.

The next step is to use something like the [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) to inspect the network requests that were made. In this case there is a clear winner, and your structured data is coming down from here:

https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Quotes/Future/6038/G